# Reload the layout after filling it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-button

I have a fragment and i create Layouts and buttons in it (programmatically) to have that kind of view :

```
<LayoutMaster>
    <Layout1>
        <Button 1>
        <Button 2>
        ...
    </Layout1>
    <Layout2>
        <Button 1>
        <Button 2>
        ...
    </Layout2>
    ...
</LayoutMaster>
```

I need that my buttons fill the screen and be all the same size. So when i used an XML file i add those properties to layouts and buttons and it worked :

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

But when i'm doing it in my java file (so i don't use a xml layout), when the fragment render, i have only one big button that is taking all the screen. So i guessed i have to refresh the view and add a LayoutMaster.invalidate() but didn't worked.

I'm doing this in the onCreateView of the fragment.

As usual, thanks again for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting wrong attributes. You are using a linear layout which stacks one view over the other and then you are setting layout_height of the button to be fill_parent that's why the first button will occupy the entire space. 
Instead you should use layout_wight attribute which helps determine how much percentage of space a view will occupy. If you want all your view to be of same size then use the layout_weight = 1 for all the views.

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

You should use these attributes all the views which needs to be of same size.

Comment: Thanks (a bit late i know) it worked ! Apply same "weight" property and tadaaaaa !